# JSON column HyperText where @currentField needs to be in the Middle of the URL

Tags: sharepoint-list, json, column-formatting

I am trying to use Microsoft's Sharepoint List Dev document to do a "Turn field values into hyperlinks (basic).  My code looks like this:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

My problem is that i need my @currentfield is in the middle of the URL and i dont know the proper "JSON Grammar" to make that happen.

Example URL:
[https://dontknowwhatiamdoing.com/something/something/"insert](https://dontknowwhatiamdoing.com/something/something/%22insert) @currentfield here/something

I have made this code work but only when the @currentField is at the end of the URL.

Please help...i know i am a Noob at this.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there! You can add more than one thing in an expression, so you can change your format to something like this:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='https://dontknowwhatiamdoing.com/something/' + @currentField + '/something'"
   }
}
```

Comment: theChrisKent Thank you so Much....worked perfectly!!!